# why the c++ program run result as "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  char* ch;
  const char *c1 = "this is a goog book\n thingking in c++";
  const char *c2 = "python good book vs cpp";
  for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
     ch[i]=c1[i];

  for(int j=0;j<50;j++)
     ch[50+j]=c2[j]; 


  char* p1=(&ch[0]);
  cout << "p1=" << p1 << endl;
}
```

compile the code in ubuntu 12.04,Able to compile，but the run result is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: Allocate some memory for `ch`. Using debugger would have pointed you there.

Comment: Skill #1 required in the software world: knowing how to research problems yourself.

Comment: @JonathanReinhart paste the code to your local crowdsourced debugging service

Answer (score 3):

You haven't allocated space for `ch`.  You can probably make it a fixed-size array:

```
char ch[128];
```

or you could allocate it from the heap:

```
char *ch = new char[128];
```

(don't forget to `delete` it when finished).

Answer (score 0):

You probably wish to concatenate   two arrays:

1. you didn't allocate space for *ch.
2. `char *c1 = "Hello World";` is a deprecated version. This should be used instead:

   `char c1[]="Hello World";`
3. If you wish to concatenate two arrays assuming the size of each to be 50 is not a good idea. You can calculate its size with the function: `strlen(c1);`  declared under `string.h` or `cstring`
4. There is an already available library function `char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );` which copies the the concatenated string into the first argument.
   As an example see [this](http://ideone.com/D6CXpY).